# Error during building with android-ndk : There are no modules to build in this project

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I cloned git from the link below and modified some lines and tried to build it.
($git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8)

But it gives me the error below and I have no idea how to resolve it.

<MY_ANDROID_NDK_PATH>/build/core/build-all.mk:89: Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!

Is anyone knows how to resolve it?

I used the command below on Ubuntu 14.04

$<MY_ANDROID_NDK_PATH>/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/ APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/Android.mk

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a look for the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188031/android-ndk-warning-there-are-no-modules-to-build-in-this-project

Answer (score 0):

You should put "Android.mk"/"Application.mk" file in to "jni" folder
OR 
set path manually :ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=./Application.mk

https://blog.csdn.net/yuanjingjiang/article/details/34857623