# Android NDK: Warning: There are no modules to build in this project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygwin

I'm new in NDK development and I'm currently facing a problem, when I try to invoke the ndk build tool from cygwin terminal:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!
```

I’m under windows (x64) and I use the r10d (64-bit) NDK.
I try to invoke it from the root of my project that contains a jni folder with a simple .c file and an Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := mycfile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mycfile.c
APP_PLATFORM    := android-19
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your *Android.mk* file is missing the macro that tells the ndk to actually build a module. Add this to the end of your file:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Btw, APP_PLATFORM variable has to be put inside *Application.mk* instead of *Android.mk*.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Is the Application.mk is another .mk file that I have to create?

Comment: yes, you can create it and directly put your application-wide variable declarations inside (ie. APP_PLATFORM:=android-19 
APP_ABI:=all
APP_STL:=...)